# rbind() returns matrix instead of a dataframe, arrange() doesnt arrange time

Tags: r, rbind

I want to combine two datasets that have same number of columns but different number of rows and I want to arrange based on ID, DATE and TIME.

```
> head(df2_1)
  C        ID DV    DATE      TIME   TSFD  TSLD  DOSE   MDV  EVID  RATE DUR      WT   AGE HEIGHT BMI         SEX    AMT     aDUR
  <fct> <int> <fct> <fct>     <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>  <fct>       <fct>  <fct>  <dbl>
1 ""    11003 .     3/14/2007 22:00     0     0    75     1     1  246. .      54.7  44.6 73     15.89851181 Female 245.97     1
2 ""    11003 .     3/14/2007 23:00     1     0    75     1     1  246. .      54.7  44.6 73     15.89851181 Female 245.97     2
3 ""    11003 .     3/15/2007 1:00      3     0    75     1     1  246. .      54.7  44.6 73     15.89851181 Female 245.97     1
4 ""    11003 .     3/15/2007 2:00      4     0    75     1     1  246. .      54.7  44.6 73     15.89851181 Female 245.97     1
5 ""    11003 .     3/15/2007 3:00      5     0    75     1     1  246. .      54.7  44.6 73     15.89851181 Female 245.97     1
6 ""    11003 .     3/15/2007 4:00      6     0    75     1     1  246. .      54.7  44.6 73     15.89851181 Female 245.97     2
> head(df2_2)
  C    ID       DV      DATE  TIME     TSFD        TSLD DOSE MDV EVID RATE DUR     WT      AGE HEIGHT         BMI    SEX AMT aDUR
1   11003 2315.688 3/16/2007 14:05 40.08333  0.08333333    0   0    0    0   .  54.66 44.60233     73 15.89851181 Female   .    .
2   11003 1651.839 3/17/2007  8:45 58.75000  0.75000000    0   0    0    0   .  54.66 44.60233     73 15.89851181 Female   .    .
3   11010  768.886 4/23/2007  9:38 21.13333  1.63333333    0   0    0    0   . 122.70 49.79877     62  49.4759054 Female   .    .
4   11010 437.5375 4/24/2007  9:15 44.75000  0.25000000    0   0    0    0   . 122.70 49.79877     62  49.4759054 Female   .    .
5   11010 489.4601 4/25/2007  9:51 69.35000 22.85000000    0   0    0    0   . 122.70 49.79877     62  49.4759054 Female   .    .
6   11021 202.3625 6/10/2007 11:00 42.08333 39.00000000    0   0    0    0   .  60.00 40.56126     69 19.53375047 Female   .    .
```

I tried `df2 <- rbind(df2_1,df2_2)`. This will return a large matrix instead of dataframe.

I then use `df2 <- rbind.data.frame(df2_1,df2_2)` This indeed returns a dataframe. But when I would like to arrange the dataframe based on ID, DATE, and TIME `df2 <- rbind.data.frame(df2_1,df2_2)%>%group_by(ID)%>%arrange(ID,DATE,TIME)`. The arrange function doesnt work for TIME. The time would go from 1:00 to 10:00, then to 2:00.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: That's because R doesn't know your column is a time, so it's just ordering it alphabetically. You need to use an appropriate class, like `POSIXct` if you combine date and time into one timestamp.

Comment: What does `class(df2_1)` and `class(df2_2)` return? R doesn't have a built in "time" data type (though it does have date+time classes). You should combine those columns into a date+time column for sorting.

Comment: You need `do.call()` for `rbind()` to work like so: `df2 <- do.call(rbind, list(df2_1, df2_2))`.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! `class(df2_1)` and `class(df2_2)` return both dataset are "data.frame". I tried `df2$TIME <-strptime(as.character(df2$TIME), "%H:%M")
df2$TIME <-format(df2$TIME, "%H:%M")` Then use arrange(). It works.